# How to use News WebPart in SP Online to read from different lists?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, newsfeed

In SP Online, I want to use an out of the box webpart to read data from any custom list and display it on the "modern" page with different look and feel (hero, carasel, list, tiles, etc...).

The news part seems to be able to read pages from the Pages list, but if I want to make another instance read from a custom list in the same site, can I do that? If I create a content type inheriting from News or Page, and assign that to a new custom list, can I make the news webpart read from that new list specifically?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The News web part only works with News pages that exist in the Site Pages library. There are no options to configure the web part to use different libraries.

The Highlighted Content web part allows you to dynamically display content from your site but does not have the same type of layouts as the News web part. The Hero web part has some similar layouts to the News but requires you to manually select content.

If you are unable to achieve your requirement out of the box, you may need to create your own web part using the SharePoint Development Framework (SPFx).

Comment: Ok I see. So if someone had various lists of different types of data on the current site (half of them look like a news item), and you wanted to display that data on the page with different UI modes (same as in news webparts), trying to utilize  as much out of the box methods as possible, is it doable (using some method) or does one need to go into SPFx to do this?

Comment: I've added some additional information to my answer, that should answer your question.

Comment: When displaying list items through highlighted content (as a tile view), the picture on the UI is blank with a  little page icon on the bottom left. Is there a way to set a picture field on the list item and then make it appear on the Highlighted Content web part?

Comment: If you have a question regarding the Highlighted Content web part, I would recommend creating a new question to avoid us creating a long comment thread.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the **Highlighted content web part** to dynamically display content from the list you want via specify list path in the Custom query.

[image]

More information:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-highlighted-content-web-part-e34199b0-ff1a-47fb-8f4d-dbcaed329efd#bkmk_customquery

Comment: When displaying list items through highlighted content (as a tile view), the picture on the UI is blank with a  little page icon on the bottom left. Is there a way to set a picture field on the list item and then make it appear on the Highlighted Content web part?

Comment: This is a workaround and we couldn't change the OOB display way.